# Finding perimeter when the hypotenuse is 1 and is the sum of the altitude and side of a triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

Let us say the hypotenuse of a triangle is 1, which is also equal to the sum of side $a$ and the altitude $h$ when taking the hypotenuse as the base. How would I find the length of side $a$ and $b$ (the other side), and thus the triangle's perimeter?

I've tried making a triangle inscribed in a circle, where the hypotenuse is the diameter of the circle so it's right-angled, and making $a$ and $b$ chords. But it leads nowhere for me. Also tried using the [geometric mean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean_theorem). I split the hypotenuse into two lengths, $p$ and $q$, where $$h^2+q^2=a^2$$ Then I defined $h=pq$ based on the theorem, which can be rewritten as $h=(1-q)q=q-q^2$. Therefore$$(q-q^2)^2+q^2=a^2\\q^4-2q^3+2q^2=a^2\\\sqrt{q^4-2q^3+2q^2}=a$$ And because $a+h=1$, we can replace them with what we derived $$\sqrt{q^4-2q^3+2q^2}+q-q^2=1\\(\sqrt{q^4-2q^3+2q^2})^2=(q^2-q+1)^2\\q^4-2q^3+2q^2=q^4-2q^3+3q^2-2q+1\\q^2-2q+1=0\\(q-1)^2,\;q=1$$ I've gone wrong somewhere but I don't know where, and I also have no idea how to solve this problem. I don't think any angle related formulas like Law of Sines or Law of Cosines would help as I also don't know how to find any angles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three equations relating $a$, $b$, and $h$:
$$\begin{align}
a+h&=1\\a^2+b^2&=1^2\\ab&=1\cdot h
\end{align}$$
The first one is given, the second is Pythagoras' theorem, the third one is the area of the triangle.
$$\begin{align}h&=1-a\\b&=\frac ha=\frac{1-a}{a}\\b&=\sqrt{1-a^2}\end{align}$$
This yields $$a^3+a^2+a-1=0$$
You can solve this numerically or use the [cubic equation formalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation). You will get $$a\approx 0.54369$$The perimeter is $$p=a+b+1=a+\frac 1a-1+1=a+\frac 1a\approx 2.382973$$

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake with $h=pq$, which should be $h^2=qp=q(1-q)$. Then, you have

$$q^2+q(1-q) = a^2$$
which leads to

$$q =a^2=\left(1-\sqrt{q(1-q)}\right)^2$$

Then, you could solve for $q$.

Answer (score 1):

From given, $a+h = 1$ and $a^2 + b^2 = 1$.

From similar triangles inside the right-angled triangle,

$$\begin{align*}\frac b1 &= \frac ha\\
ab &= h\\
a+ab &= 1\\
b &= \frac{1-a}{a}\\
a^2 + \left(\frac{1-a}{a}\right)^2 &= 1\\
a^4 + 1 - 2a + a^2 &= a^2\\
a^4 - 2a + 1 &= 0\\
(a-1)(a^3 +a^2+a-1)&=0
\end{align*}$$

There is one real root where $0<a<1$:
$$a\approx 0.543689012692076$$

Answer (score 0):

The area of the triangle is $\frac{1}{2}\times 1\times h$ (considering hypotenus as base). And is also $\frac{1}{2}\times a\times b$. Thus $ab=h$ and $a^2+b^2=1$. Therefore $a+b=\sqrt{a^2+b^2+2ab}$. Thus $a+b+1=1+\sqrt{1+2h}$ is the perimeter. Hope its correct.

Comment: It's incomplete. You should get rid of $h$ as well. You know $a+h=1$

Comment: I though $h$ was given. My bad.